# How do I find all git repositories, including bare ones?

Tags: git

Usually when looking for git repositories I look for a `.git` directory, but that doesn't always work.  Submodule worktrees have a `.git` file, submodules aren't always checked out, and submodule repositories (and bare repositories) can be anywhere.

I want to find every repository cloned from say github, but finding every repository's hard enough.  Is there a command or oneliner to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to find every repository cloned from say github`? Do you want the github URL? Or are you looking for paths on the local disk? If so do you want the metadata directory or the source directory?

Comment: @Guildencrantz I mean I want to run `git config remote.origin.url` in every repo, running the command isn't hard, it's finding the repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal git repository contains a `HEAD` file and two
directories, `objects` and `refs`.

So you can tell `find` to find directories that meet those criteria.
`HEAD` is a pretty unusual name, let's look for that:

```
# find all repositories
find -name HEAD -execdir test -d refs -a -d objects \; \
    -printf %h\\n   # or if your `find` doesn't have `-printf`, just `-print`
```

will do. This finds the repository, not its worktree; to find worktrees,
finding `.git` is still the best way

```
find -name .git
```

or if the trailing `.git` is annoying

```
find -name .git -printf %h\\n
```

Comment: Note that this requires that your `find` have both `-execdir` and `-printf`. The former seems to be pretty standard now but `-printf` is still missing on some MacOS and FreeBSD systems, at least. I see some versions of `find` either strip `.` from `$PATH` or refuse to allow `-execdir` if `$PATH` has `.` in it, too. Which is probably good. :-) (I don't put `.` in my path.)

Comment: Yow. Gotta smile at the innocence of anyone who'd run with `.` in `PATH`...  Thanks for the note, I folded in the `-printf` note.